# Change Activity into Fragment

Tags: list, layout, android-activity, view, fragment

I am quite new at Android. 
So I am a bit confused of working with fragments.

I have found a very great [tutorial.](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/)

So I have working code. But it is the layout oft a normal activity.

Then I tried to include it into a navigation drawer.
So the list view with data will only be shown when the menu item has been selected.

On the fragment View there is a never ending loading Dialog.

While debugging I have figured out that the code loads still the data and inserts it into feedItems.
So feedItems is filled correctly.
Now after listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() there happens nothing.

So here that is my code:

```java
public class FragmentNews extends ListFragment {

    private static final String TAG = FragmentNews.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://address.com";

    public FragmentNews(){}

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        loadDataForNews();
    }

    private void loadDataForNews(){
        listView = this.getListView();

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity(), feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }
    }

    // List View Feed
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Can the problem be that the inflater of listAdapter is null?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work properly.
Try removing

```
listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity(), feedItems);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

from loadDataForNews() and adding in
place of `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: It does not work... There is still the loading dialog